# Layer model expects 1 input(s), but it received 2 input tensors

Tags: keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to run the following simple code.

The image generator returns two images (so , the labels are images also).

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Input

def load_image(file):
    image = cv2.imread(file, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    return image

file = './B2.jpeg'

def image_generator(image):
    i = 0
    while True:
        X = image
        y = image
        
        X = np.expand_dims(X, axis=0)
        y = np.expand_dims(y, axis=0)
        
        i = i + 1
        yield [X, y]

inputs = Input(shape=(None, None, 3))
x = Conv2D(filters=3,
           kernel_size=3,
           padding='same',
           activation='relu',
           strides=1)(inputs)

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)
model.compile(loss='mae',
              optimizer='adam')


image = load_image(file)
model.fit(image_generator(image), epochs=1)
```

and it gives me:

```
ValueError: Layer model expects 1 input(s), but it received 2 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, None, None, None) dtype=uint8>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(None, None, None, None) dtype=uint8>]

I am using tensorflow 2.4.1 and keras 2.4.0
```

I am using this image

[image: this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your case :

```
image_generator(image)
```

return a `<generator object image_generator>`. For access at resource you use `next(generator_object)`.

test this, work for me :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Input

def load_image(file):
    image = cv2.imread(file, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    return image

file = './image.jpg'

def image_generator(image):
    while True:
        X = image
        y = image
        
        X = np.expand_dims(X, axis=0)
        y = np.expand_dims(y, axis=0)
        
        return (X, y)

inputs = Input(shape=(None, None, 3))
x = Conv2D(filters=3,
           kernel_size=3,
           padding='same',
           activation='relu',
           strides=1)(inputs)

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)
model.compile(loss='mae',
              optimizer='adam')


image = load_image(file)
testx,testy = image_generator(image)
model.fit(testx,testy ,epochs=1)
```